# How do I make a game that can transition from 2D to 3D?

Tags: 2d, 3d

My plan is to start from an really old game and build my way up to todays graphics and games. So for example start with Pong and then go to Space Invaders, then go to Zelda and Super Mario. But then I need to make the first 2D games change into 3D games. How do I do that?

Comment: This question is very broad, and obvious. All you need to do is transition between the different "games" that have different graphics. Your plan seems okay to me... Also, this really isn't an appropriate question, what are you asking?

Comment: I think he's asking how to make a game that _plays 2D_, suddenly start playing in _3D_.

Comment: I voted to close because you asked about which tech to use.  But I think you have a salvageable question here; please modify it to ask about the process of rendering in both formats.  And as always: be specific and mention what you've already tried.  You should also change your question title to reflect the question itself, rather than the context you are interested in.

Comment: I believe you mean a game similar to [Evoland](http://evoland.shirogames.com/)?

Answer (score 9):

That's easy.  Just program your game with the z-axis aligned to to the camera forward direction.  Set z=0.  Everything appears flat, or 2D.

[image]

Skew the axis a bit to reveal the world is actually 3d

[image]

So in short, to make a 2D game appear 3D, it has to be 3D in the first place.  You cleverly draw the 3D scene to make it *appear* 2D.  Then later you can change the camera angles to show it is really 3D.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will try to do this and see how it goes

Comment: Basically what I am asking is how to make lets say a cutscene between one game and another. 
The game before the cutscene is 2d and the game afterwards is 3d. How can i do this and what is the best way to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you would essentially need to make two different games. That or you could create your game in 3D then force the camera to render orthographically and restrict game movement in the x and y plane. There isn't exactly an easy way to change a game from being 2D to 3D since both perspectives require radically different design and control.

Answer (score 0):

I have messed a bit with Unity and XNA both of which force you to develop in a 3D environment, even when making 2D games. In order to do this you need to ignore the 'Z' axis and just focus on 'X' and 'Y'. If you're looking on how to make a 2D game, there are several tutorials out there that aren't hard to find.

To transition from a 2D to a 3D game could mean several different things. You could go from traditional 2D side scroller (original mario) to 3D adventure (super mario 64) to 3D side scroller (splosion man) (its more like a 2D sidescroller with 3D textures) so you need to know what kind of 3D game you want to make.

If you want to make a 3D side scroller then just change objects from 2D objects to 3D and TADAA you're pretty much done. However, if you are wanting to go from 2D to 3D adventure, I would suggest the advice of @bobobobo (Master of Fist of the Nose Hair).

I would definitely learn how to make 2D and 3D games separately first THEN learn how to transition since you would know more about both.

Comment: I know how to make both 2D and 3D games and i will definitely try what @bobobobo said. What i want is to go from classic Super Mario to Super mario 64

Comment: Check out a game that was made called  ["Fez"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fez_%28video_game%29) Its not exactly what you want but it has similar elements. If you watch some of the videos on YouTube you can get a visual representation of what @bobobobo was saying. It should just be a camera trick. hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a 3d dev, but I think that all you have to do is make scenes for each game,3d or 2d, then swap them

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/104915)